# How can I encode an url for wget?

Tags: bash, wget, url, sh

I am looking for a way to convert a string to a *clean* url.

For example :

```
 wget http://myurl.com/toto/foo bar.jpg
```

This is going to download `http://myurl.com/toto/foo` and `http://bar.jpg`.

I want to download `http://myurl.com/toto%20bar.jpg`.

I tried some flag like `--restrict-file-names=ascii` but without success.

I do not want a way to encode not a kind of replace one-by-one.

Any idea ?

Comment: You can try escaping the space by a backslash (\\)... wget http://myurl.com/tot/foo\ bar.jpg

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Contain the URL in quotes:

```
wget "http://myurl.com/toto/foo bar.jpg"
```

This is a general way of containing strings with spaces as a single argument.

Comment: Damn ... I should think about this. Thank you.